# Convert a list to tuple of lists with 3 values and vice versa in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I'm trying to create an image by providing set of pixel images(RGB values).

I have created a set of 1-D array, 13 values, and want each value to be copied as RGB value for the pixel.

like
I have

```
[12,13,14,15,65,66,54,12,34,77,88,33,56]
```

13 values. i want to create an image out of this so first of all i pic up the nearest perfect square, in this case 16. so i need to generate 16 RGB values array like this by using existing 13 values and filling the rest with default values. (here the default value is 0)

```
[
   [(12,12,12), (13,13,13), (14,14,14), (15,15,15)],
   [(65,65,65), (66,66,66), (54,54,54), (12,12,12)],
   [(34,34,34), (77,77,77), (88,88,88), (33,33,33)],
   [(56,56,56), (0,0,0), (0,0,0), (0,0,0)]
]
```

I know how to convert this 2-d list into image using pillow. I need help in creating this list and convert it back to the original list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
arr = [12,13,14,15,65,66,54,12,34,77,88,33,56]

res = []
for k in arr:
    res.append(tuple([k] * 3))  # Create list of three k elements and convert it to a tuple with tuple statement.
while(len(res)<16):
    res.append(tuple([0] * 3))  # Fill remaining tuples of three zeroes

result = [res[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, len(res), 4)]   # Make chunks of resultant array of size 4

print(result)
```

Note:- Convert a list to tuple or vice versa as follows.

```
listA = [1,2,3]
tupleA = tuple(listA) 
print(tupleA)
listB = list(tupleA)
print(listB)
```